# How does this homebrew dual shield feat compare to existing feats?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, homebrew-review, shield

> **Shield Warrior**
>
> You have mastered the art of using shields as weapons. You gain the following benefits:
>
> - You can benefit from up to 2 shields (including stacking their bonuses to AC).
> - When using a shield as an improvised weapon, you have proficiency with it.
> - You can don or doff two shields when you would normally only be able to don or doff one.

**How does this compare to existing RAW feats, balance-wise?**

## Known interactions

### Shield Master

- Completely non-redundant with Shield Warrior
- Possible balance issue with adding the AC bonus of two shields to Dex saves when combined with Shield Warrior

### Tavern Brawler

- Proficiency with improvised weapons overlaps with Shield Warrior's proficiency with improvised weapons (shields)

### Dual Wielder

- Allows two-weapon fighting with two shields
- [Looks like](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119921/does-using-a-shield-as-an-improvised-weapon-work-with-dual-wielder-feat) +1 AC would not be applied, as [improvised weapons are not melee weapons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/119926/are-improvised-weapons-used-in-melee-actually-melee-weapons)

Comment: Is the point of it to be able to create a mini PC version of Fire Giant Dreadnoughts from VGtM?

Comment: @J.E That's one example that I had in mind, yeah. But the FGD has lots of abilities a PC with this wouldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's not overpowered under most circumstances

Assuming non-magical shields, it compares fairly well with Dual Wielder. Dual Wielder gives +1 AC and allows two-handed fighting with non-light weapons. Your feat gives 3 AC more when shields are held but doesn't allow two-weapon fighting and indeed only works when the character wields a shield, which is a pretty bad weapon even if you have proficiency with it. It's a fair trade.

I expect it can become overpowered when the character with this feat has access to multiple magical shields with convenient synergy, eg. Shield of Missile attraction and Arrow-Catching Shield.

### It's not a good feat

Giving away offensive  capability for defensive capability (in this case, by dual-wielding shields) tends to draw out combats because it reduces the expected damage output of both sides. Balanced or not, I think that's a good enough reason to not introduce this feat in your game.

Comment: Is a warcaster cleric (Holy symbol on a shield) a consideration when looking at balance? No real loss of offence but hugely improved AC.

Comment: @SeriousBri wouldn't the two shields interfere with certain spells (mainly the ones with somatic but no material components)?

Comment: @J.E possibly, to be honest I have never played at a table that even considers v,s,m in normal play, which only increases the power of this mobile one man shield wall.

Comment: Wielding two shields not only makes somatic components impossible, it also makes doing anything at all with your hands impossible. ANd it takes an action to remove a shield (which, how do you do that if you don't have a free hand?)

Comment: @NautArch in this case you do it even faster then with just one shield and no feat :-) Maybe you have it on a piece of string and you just kinda drop them to dangle..?

Comment: @NautArch because of the feat, which says: "You can don or doff two shields when you would normally only be able to don or doff one."

Comment: @Erik d'oh! Reading fail. My other points do remain in that you no longer have hands to use while wielding like this. It's not like a two-handed weapon where you can release a hand.

Comment: @NautArch I took magical shields into brief consideration (see the middle paragraph)

Comment: To be honest if I had thjs feat I woukd make an untouchable Vocal spell caster. Then again there are some official feats that are equally ridiculous with specialized builds